# how to add color option in wordpress customize

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress theme, and I like to add a COLOR option in customize page, so that admin can change background-color, text-color, link-color etc. I don't have any plugins installed in my wordpress directory except "Akismet", and except "mytheme" (mytheme is the name of my theme) all themes have that option in the customize page. 
my question is how can I add that COLOR option in the customize page which appears just after the "Site Identity" option.
Thank you

Comment: i think you use this plugin  https://wordpress.org/plugins/fourteen-colors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this:

[Customizer WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)

Something like this should work:

```
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_textcolor' , array(
        'default'     => "#000000",
        'transport'   => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_textcolor', array(
        'label'        => __( 'Header Color', 'mytheme' ),
        'section'    => 'colors',
    ) ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );

function mytheme_customize_css()
{
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        h2 { color: #<?php echo get_theme_mod('header_textcolor', "#000000"); ?>; }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mytheme_customize_css');
```

Output via `wp_head();`

```
<style type="text/css">
     h1 {color:#000000;}
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for reply..
I have paste the PHP code in functions.php file and the CSS in the style.css file.....now the page does not display anything

Comment: @ShanBiswas, see updated answer please. Did you get it to work?

Comment: hello...I already put the codes you updated above, it is working now, anyway thank you vary much.....!!

Comment: @ShanBiswas, glad i could help, please accept the answer and vote it up :)